# np.select returns error "Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1?"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe for which I get an error when trying to create a new column using np.select.

```
conditions_decisions = [(Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='a'),
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='b'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='c'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='d'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='e'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='f'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='g')]
choices_decision=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
Daily_Report['Paymentmethod']=np.select(conditions_decisions, choices_decision)
```

I would like to get a new column named "Paymentmethod" in my data frame Daily_Report based on the elements in the "Payment_type" column: if  "a" in "Payment_type" then "1" in "Paymentmethod" etc.

### I get the below error, can't figure out why I am passing 2 itmes.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3077             try:
-> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer()

KeyError: 'Paymentmethod'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in set(self, item, value, check)
   4242         try:
-> 4243             loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   4244         except KeyError:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             except KeyError:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   3081 

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer()

KeyError: 'Paymentmethod'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-4fca93a5ac39> in <module>()
      7                 (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='g')]
      8 choices_decision=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
----> 9 Daily_Report['Paymentmethod']=np.select(conditions_decisions, choices_decision)
     10 #Daily_Report

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3117         else:
   3118             # set column
-> 3119             self._set_item(key, value)
   3120 
   3121     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3193         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
   3194         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
-> 3195         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3196 
   3197         # check if we are modifying a copy

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   2598 
   2599     def _set_item(self, key, value):
-> 2600         self._data.set(key, value)
   2601         self._clear_item_cache()
   2602 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in set(self, item, value, check)
   4244         except KeyError:
   4245             # This item wasn't present, just insert at end
-> 4246             self.insert(len(self.items), item, value)
   4247             return
   4248 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates)
   4345 
   4346         block = make_block(values=value, ndim=self.ndim,
-> 4347                            placement=slice(loc, loc + 1))
   4348 
   4349         for blkno, count in _fast_count_smallints(self._blknos[loc:]):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype, fastpath)
   3203                      placement=placement, dtype=dtype)
   3204 
-> 3205     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   3206 
   3207 # TODO: flexible with index=None and/or items=None

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
   2301 
   2302         super(ObjectBlock, self).__init__(values, ndim=ndim,
-> 2303                                           placement=placement)
   2304 
   2305     @property

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    123             raise ValueError(
    124                 'Wrong number of items passed {val}, placement implies '
--> 125                 '{mgr}'.format(val=len(self.values), mgr=len(self.mgr_locs)))
    126 
    127     def _check_ndim(self, values, ndim):

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion here is better use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) or [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
d = {'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3', 'd':'4', 'e':'5', 'f':'6', 'g':'7'}
Daily_Report['Paymentmethod'] = Daily_Report['Payment_type'].replace(d)

Daily_Report['Paymentmethod'] = (Daily_Report['Payment_type'].map(d)
                                  .fillna(Daily_Report['Payment_type']))
```

Your error means duplicated columns names:

```
Daily_Report = pd.DataFrame({
        'Payment_type':list('abcdef'),
         'F':list('aaabbb')
}).rename(columns={'F':'Payment_type'})
print (Daily_Report)
  Payment_type Payment_type
0            a            a
1            b            a
2            c            a
3            d            b
4            e            b
5            f            b

conditions_decisions = [(Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='a'),
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='b'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='c'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='d'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='e'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='f'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='g')]
choices_decision=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
Daily_Report['Paymentmethod']=np.select(conditions_decisions, choices_decision)
print (Daily_Report)
```

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Solution is rename duplicated columns like:

```
Daily_Report = pd.DataFrame({
        'Payment_type':list('abcdef'),
         'A':list('aaabbb'),
         'F':list('aaabbb')
}).rename(columns={'F':'Payment_type'})
print (Daily_Report)
  Payment_type  A Payment_type
0            a  a            a
1            b  a            a
2            c  a            a
3            d  b            b
4            e  b            b
5            f  b            b

s = Daily_Report.columns.to_series()
Daily_Report.columns = s + s.groupby(s).cumcount().astype(str).radd('_').replace('_0', '')
print (Daily_Report)
  Payment_type  A Payment_type_1
0            a  a              a
1            b  a              a
2            c  a              a
3            d  b              b
4            e  b              b
5            f  b              b
```

---

```
conditions_decisions = [(Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='a'),
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='b'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='c'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='d'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='e'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='f'), 
                (Daily_Report['Payment_type']=='g')]
choices_decision=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
Daily_Report['Paymentmethod']=np.select(conditions_decisions, choices_decision)
print (Daily_Report)

  Payment_type  A Payment_type_1 Paymentmethod
0            a  a              a             1
1            b  a              a             2
2            c  a              a             3
3            d  b              b             4
4            e  b              b             5
5            f  b              b             6
```

Comment: Your simulation is working for me as well. I also do have np.select used in my code earlier up my code for a different column and it works fine. When I reach that piece of code, it fails with the   Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1. In fact my df is coming from a csv brought in with pd.read_csv. (not sure if this info counts for something).

Comment: You're right,  it was a duplicate column. Thanks a lot!